# Gazebo Simulation - Can't Find Node

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am attempting to run a simulation of a Turtlebot3 package on Ubuntu16.02 Gazebo. Everything seems to be going fine until the last .launch file (which of course is the one that I really want to see the behavior of), where I receive the error `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [explore_lite/explore]: can't locate node [explore] in package [explore_lite]` .

- First, I launch `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch`.
- Second, I launch `roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_slam.launch slam_methods:=gmapping` since my other code is dependent on it.
  -Then `roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation move_base.launch`
- Last, I launch the following which is where I get the previously mentioned error `roslaunch explore_lite explore_costmap.launch` .

I'd love to be able to use Gazebo effectively, but there's just not much documentation out there that shows how to actually test your own code - just how to bring up Gazebo. Anyway, thanks for reading!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296764/gazebo-simulation---can%27t-find-node/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @AmateurHour,

Have you installed the 'explore_lite' package?
I installed and ran it and it ran without any problems.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-explore-lite
roslaunch explore_lite explore.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-09**:
Yes... you ran it on Gazebo?

**Comment by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) on 2018-07-09**:
Yes! The execution screen is as follows.
https://pasteboard.co/HtIAP5y.png

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-09**:
I did a rosclean purge and rebooted my pc and that seems to have fixed it, thank you!!